# get data with shortcode

Tags: shortcode, wpdb

i have a wp db. and i added a table "wp_mapmus"

now i want to show these datas on post page with shortcode.
But there is an error. and i dont know php very well. i only use same plugins.
what is the correct code ?

my code:

```
function veri_cek($atts, $content = null) { extract( shortcode_atts( array( 'id' => '0', ), $atts ) );

    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix . 'mapmus';
    $sql = 'SELECT point FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = '.$id.'';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    foreach ( $results as $result )
{
    return ' Point: '.$result.' ';
}
}
add_shortcode( 'veri', 'veri_cek' );
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it doesnt show anythng.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your error as well, but one thing you are doing wrong. Returning data.

You should be 'collecting' them and then returning.

```
$data = '';
foreach ( $results as $result )
{
    $data .= ' Point: '.$result.' ';
}

return $data;
```

Try this loop.

Comment: thanks but it break the page.

Comment: Then give all your code, or a screen how it breaks page. Since in the loop is nothing, that would cause a breaking of the code. This depends on a lot of factors, maybe a variable `$result` is an array, and we are echoing it. I just worked with your code, which you provided.